# Solve $\cos x \cos 3x -\sin x\sin 3x =0 \,\,\, \forall x \in [0,\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

We had this problem

$$\cos x \cos 3x -\sin x\sin 3x =0 \,\,\, \forall x \in [0,\pi]$$

in an assignment and I wasn't able to solve without graphing the function first. I tried using $\cos (x+y)$ but that didn't work out. Can someone please provide some steps?

Thanks!

Comment: The identity for $\cos(x+y)$ should work. What happened?

Comment: I just got $\cos (4x)$ then where do I go from there? How do I figure out the rest of the solutions?

Comment: Common @gekkostate: $$\cos 4x=0\iff 4x=\frac{2n+1}2\pi\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb Z\ldots$$

Comment: Do you know for which values of $A$ $\cos A$ is zero? Then I'm sure you can work out the solutions of $\cos4x=0$ for $0\le x\le\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. If you try using the identity $\cos(x+3x)$ You should get exactly the same expression above. Then it remains to figure out when $\cos(4x)=0$ As cosine is zero at odd multiples of $\frac{\pi}2$, $\cos(4x)$ will be zero at odd multiples of $\frac{\pi}8$. In this case $\frac{\pi}8$,$\frac{3\pi}8$,$\frac{5\pi}8$, and $\frac{7\pi}8$.

Comment: Suppose that I was asked to find the answer for when cos equalled $1/2$ then how would I find all of solutions? Do I have to just know that the answer occurs at specific intervals?

Comment: Nevermind! Got it! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\cos \alpha \cdot \cos 3\alpha - \sin \alpha \cdot \sin 3\alpha = \cos(\alpha + 3\alpha)$$

Now you can continue on your own.